# Merge 2 commits to one

Tags: git

let's say I have a text.txt file on my local git repo, And I made 3 commits to the remote repo:
commit 1:

```
john
```

commit 2:

```
john
Paul
```

commit 3:

```
john
Paul
David
```

My goal is to being able to look at the changes that were made after commit 1, so I try to merge the last 2 commits to one. How can i do that?

I tried:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git push origin HEAD --force
```

but it just delete the last 2 commits

Comment: `git rebase -i HEAD~2` https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-squash

Comment: google about git squash. BTW you are trying to view changes or rewrite history by squishing two commits? One part of question says 1 version other says 2 version.

Comment: I describe my thought process, I try to view history of changes after the first commit by  squishing  2 last  commits

Comment: git rebase -i HEAD~2  ---> this gives errors                                         
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you have unstaged changes so you will first need to commit or stash them e.g `git add <file> && git commit -m "message"` or `git stash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interactive rebase is quite the overkill here. You can simply reset then recommit.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m "message describing changes in commits 2 and 3"
git push --force-with-lease
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to perform an **interactive rebase**. Set the mode to `pick` on commit "john", `edit` on commit "Paul", then set the mode to `squash` on commit "David".

Essentially, this will `squash` David into Paul, and you'll have the changes from both in a single commit.

Using the `edit` keyword on Paul will allow you to rename the commit before running the rebase, which may make your commit history clearer. If you don't care about that, you can just use the `pick` mode on "Paul" as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to view history of changes

To view history, do not squash (squish); that *changes* history. The command for *viewing* history is `git log`.

In particular you would say

```
git log --patch
```

If the question is how one commit differs from another (i.e. what changes lead from one to the other), the command is `git diff`.

Comment: How can I view changes from HEAD~1 to HEAD~7 for example?

Comment: You would say `git diff HEAD~1 HEAD~7`

Answer (score 0):

```
m1--------m2-------m3 (old -> new)
```

1. git rebase -i HEAD~2
2. change **pick** to **s** or **squash** (popup appear) ( commit m3)
3. save (wq)

result:

```
 m1--------m2' (old -> new)
```

Comment: @yonatanelizarov ,if it resolve your problem or useful for you, please upvote or accept it